# Consistent way to check if an np.array is datetime-like

Tags: datetime, numpy

I'm dong some unit testing and I need to make sure a function always returns a np.datetime64-like object. However, they can be of any unit (year, day, nanosecond, etc).

I've tried:

```
comp = function_returns_datetime_array(inp)

assert isinstance(comp.dtype, np.datetime64)
assert issubclass(comp.dtype, np.datetime64)
assert issubclass(type(comp.dtype), np.datetime64)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`issubdtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html#numpy.issubdtype):

```
np.issubdtype(comp.dtype, np.datetime64)
```

Comment: Hi IanS, doesn't seem to work for complex datetime64, see if you can help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60714568/typeerror-data-type-not-understood-comparing-dtype-np-datetime64 thanks alot

Answer (score 4):

Currently I'm using:

```
assert 'datetime64' in str(comp.dtype)
```

It leaves a bad taste in my mouth (since it relies on other behavior), but its all I can some up with.