# "TypeError: data type not understood" comparing dtype np.datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

as per this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063362/consistent-way-to-check-if-an-np-array-is-datetime-like/39020498#39020498), I'm comparing a subtype **datetime64[ns, US/Central]** to **np.datetime64**:

```
        columns = self._obj.columns
        for dtype in self._obj.dtypes:
            print("testing:", dtype)
            if np.issubdtype(dtype, np.datetime64):
               ...
```

```
testing: datetime64[ns, US/Central]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2ddcb445a42c> in <module>
...
...(self, dataframe, *dataframes)
    147         for dtype in self._obj.dtypes:
    148             print("testing:", dtype)
--> 149             if np.issubdtype(dtype, np.datetime64):

...
TypeError: data type not understood
```

if run head() in this dataframe I get normal timestamps in that column:

```
ts
0   2020-02-22 12:11:40-06:00   NaN
1   2020-02-22 12:11:41-06:00   NaN
```

pandas.**version** '1.0.2' 
numpy.**version** '1.18.1'
any ideas? thanks

Comment: You could open an issue in GitHub, I feel like it should work. See if you can make it a pure numpy issue (accessing the underlying numpy array through `.values`), and raise it there rather than in pandas: https://github.com/numpy/numpy

Comment: Did you raise and issue, and did it get fixed within numpy? Also, how do you add a timezone to a numpy datetime64, or is that pandas?

Comment: Nevermind, must be pandas. Still seems like the latest numpy has this issue though.

Answer (score 1):

not ideal, but I fixed this with string comparison:

```
if (str(dtype).startswith("datetime64")):
   ...
```