# Best way to determine if numpy array is a datetime64?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a numpy array, I would like to test if it is a datetime64 or just a normal numeric array.  I use this in some plotting functions that accept both options, however I can't do a `np.isnan` or `np.isinf` on datetime64's and I can't do a `np.isnat` on numeric arrays, so I need to know which is which.

The problem is that I get different answers based on how the original array was created.

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x = np.datetime64('now', 'us')
>>> y = np.array([datetime.datetime.now()], dtype='datetime64[us]')

>>> isinstance(x, np.datetime64)
True
>>> isinstance(y, np.datetime64)
False
```

The best I've come up with so far is:

```py
>>> str(x.dtype).startswith('datetime64')
True
>>> str(y.dtype).startswith('datetime64')
True
```

Is this the best option, or is there a better way?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063362/consistent-way-to-check-if-an-np-array-is-datetime-like/39020498)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try the [np.issubdtype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html#numpy-issubdtype) function.

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: x = np.datetime64('now', 'us')

In [4]: y = np.array([datetime.datetime.now()], dtype='datetime64[us]')

In [5]: np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.datetime64)
Out[5]: True

In [6]: np.issubdtype(y.dtype, np.datetime64)
Out[6]: True
```